# Spring boot data initilization custom path

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app. I want to keep the data initialization files in the package itself like the below structure.

```
something.com.package1
  --model.class
  --service.class
  --controller.class
  --mydata.sql
something.com.package2
  --model.class
  --service.class
  --controller.class
  --mydata2.sql
```

I am able to achieve the same using `classpath` in `spring.datasource.data`
application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.data=classpath:com/idot/userAccessForm/*.sql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xx
spring.datasource.username=xx
spring.datasource.password=xx
```

When I try to run this from eclipse as a spring boot app **it works fine**

But if I build a jar using `mnv clean package` and run using `java -jar app.jar` the files are not read.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.novartis</groupId>
    <artifactId>idot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>idot</name>
    <description>Idot App</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How can I achieve the same?

**Edit:**

If the file is kept in `/src/main/resources` as `data.sql` it works fine running the jar and running from eclipse but I want to keep data for each model in it's package itself. I also understand I can use `liquibase` or `flywaydb` but why it's not working in this scenario?

Comment: Show your POM. Are you using the maven-resources-plugin? It needs to be customised to pick up resources from src/main/java.

Answer (score 0):

Normally init.sql and data.sql for popular  data sources resides in resources folder (src/main/resources) which is automatically executed on startup.

If you want to use schema.sql you should set:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: I understand that if it's part of src/main/resources it would be picked up automatically, but I want to configure otherwise. I neither want to use schema.sql